# Show that the fiber $f^{-1}(a)$ is finite if $a∈ℝ,a≠0$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, analyticity, fiber-bundles

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a real analytic function. If $f$ has infinitely many zeros, then we know that the fiber $f^{-1}(0)$ is an infinite discrete and countable set. Let $a∈ℝ,a≠0$, we know also that the fiber $f^{-1}(a)$ is a discrete set unless $f = a$. Then my **question** is: Some observations show that **the number of the fibers $f^{-1}(a)$ is finite** (not the number of elements in each fiber). However, I am not able to prove that. We can define the equivalence relation as: $$xRy⇔f(x)=f(y)$$

The equivalence classes of the relation $R$ are the fibers $f^{-1}(x)$. If the number of those fibers is infinite, then this will create a contradiction with the fact that $f$ is an analytic function.

Comment: Could you be slightly more specific about these equivalence classes?

Comment: @HSN: I add the expression of the equivalence relation in the question.

Comment: @AR1: Your equivalence relation doesn't divide the fibre into different (more than one) classes though.

Comment: @Michalis: You want to say that there is one equivalence class?

Comment: You're equivalence relation divides the domain $\mathbb{R}$ into the different fibres. It doesn't divide fibres into classes as you suggest.

Comment: Then the question is to show that the number of those fibers is finite.

Comment: Since every fiber is discrete, it is at most countable. Then, is your result would be true, it would prove that $\mathbb R$ is countable...If $f$ is not constant there must be (uncountably) infinitely many  fibers.

Comment: P.S. If $f(x)=x$, how many fibers do you have? ;)

Comment: The function $f(z) = \sin z$ has infinitely many zeros, so that $f^{-1}(0)$ is countably infinite.  Also, $f^{-1}(1)$ is countably infinite, so it is not always true that $f^{-1}(a)$ is finite.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @AntonioVargas : My **question** is:  Some observations show that **the number of the fibers $f^{-1}(a)$ is finite** (not the number of elements in each fiber).

Comment: @AR1 But $\sin z$ has a fiber at every $a \in [-1,1]$, and thus has uncountably many fibers.  Am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Thank you very much for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion in comments: the fibers of $f$ are in bijective correspondence with the points in the range of $f$. The range of a nonconstant continuous real function is uncountable.

---

Side remark: when editing a question, it is advisable to check if the title still matches the question.